# Object Reference seems not set properly(although it was set properly) in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas

In my Unity project, although I set the object reference to the instance of the object, I still get the error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object QuestionCode.CountryChange (UnityEngine.GameObject
>   button_country) (at Assets/scripts/QuestionCode.cs:898)

However, I am sure that there's no problem with object settings because it was working properly before with exactly same settings I have now.

But I discovered a weird property now and suspect if that might be the problem. As you can see from the figures, my main script for the game has a circular shape(I didn't understand why a script had a geometrical shape anyway) and remains outside of the canvas. This situation doesn't make any sense to me at all.

And unfortunately I can't provide my code here since it's too long and I don't think that there's a problem with the script. So what possible solutions do I have here?

These circular shapes form my QuestionCode script:
[image]

Here, you can see Canvas and QuestionCode together. Some parts of questioncode remain outside of the canvas and some cover the whole canvas. And also you can see the error in the console.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The 'geometrical shape' you're seeing in the editor is not from the script. It's a component that's been added to the object somehow. Turn everything off on the gameobject until it goes away, and there's your culprit. That being said, the component being added to your gameobject is not going to cause that error. The error you're getting is definitely from your script, which is most likely because a variable has not been set in the editor. From the pictures you provided, I am unable to see but I'm willing to bet that it's a public variable that has not been set.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about what did you do in your code. This error message is so basic that no one can guess the reason. You should check your code following this hit:

An Unity object can NOT work properly with some C# operator like `?.`. because an object shows invalid in Inspector windows is still `not null` in C# code. In this case, it triggers the error message come out.